# Configure Apache virtual hosts - all subdomains to 404

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

It's the first time that I try to configure apache so I hope you can help me.

This is what I want to achieve:

- All undefined subdomains should lead to *not found* if they aren't defined
- Root folder should never be accessible

Now this is what I have so far:

*my.conf*

```
ServerName server1 (is hostname)

ServerSignature off
ServerTokens prod

Options -Includes
Options -ExecCGI
```

*sites-available/default*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /htdocs

    <Directory />
            Options None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /htdocs/>
            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*sites-available/example*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /htdocs/example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, my questions are:

- Does the "Directory /" from the default-config also apply on the example.com site? Or do I need to put it in there, too. Or should it rather be in the my.conf?
- Same question for "Directory /htdocs/" - should I put this in the example.com-config, too? Of course like "Directory /htdocs/example/" then.
- At the moment every subdomain of the example.com is leading to the default directory. How can I prevent that? Only the Server IP should lead there - if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For undefined subdomains**
you could add a new virtualhost AFTER all known subdomain.example.com virtualhosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.example.com
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>
```

`Redirect 404 /` replies with "404 Not found" on every request.

---

**The scope of configuration directives**

Directives can be server wide or restricted to particular directories, files, virtualhosts etc. Directory, DirectoryMatch, Files, FilesMatch, If, IfDefine, IfModule, IfVersion, Location, LocationMatch, Proxy, ProxyMatch and VirtualHost are called [Configuration Section Containers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html): directives within them only affects inside the container.

In the following example "Require all denied" affects on /htdocs/private.html and "Options -Indexes" affects to "/htdocs" but only within VirtualHost with ServerName example.com.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    <Directory /htdocs/>
        Options -Indexes
        <Files private.html>
           Require all denied
        </Files>
    </Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: Thank you. That surely will work. Do you also have an answer to my other questions?

Comment: I just added section about scope of configuration directives which should answer to rest of your questions.

Comment: Okay, so if I got you right I have to put the "Directory /" to my.conf to apply it on everything. Then only put it in a virtual host if I want do override it, right?